# Is there a solution to the constant unhandled exceptions that Powerpivot throws in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

Each time I perform certain actions with Powerpivot in Excel 2013 it throws an exception about not being unable to cast a COM object to an interface. This happens most notably every time I try to type a function for a calculated column and when I leave the formula bar. If I click continue, the program continues as normal but this starts to become an annoyance after a while.

I have researched the error but documented cases are few and forum posts about this error just seem to be ignored.

Is there a solution to this problem such as an update or a different way to use it or should I just suck it up and live with it?

Below is a screenshot of the error dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When certain **PowerPivot** actions in **Microsoft Office 2013** have an **Unhandled exception** occur related to `'Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI' - Library not registered` try to . . .

### Repair Office 2013

> Go to **Control Panel** and from **Program and Features**, highlight
>   the **Microsoft Office 2013** entry on your system, *right-click* and
>   select **Change**, and then when the **Office** window pops up for
>   **How would you like to repair your Office programs?** start by trying **Quick Repair**.  If that doesn't resolve the problem, reboot, confirm there's still an issue and then try to **Online Repair**.
>
> [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Microsoft Office 2007/2010/2013/2016 (Win) - Repairing Corrupted Program Files](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=9344)
- [How to use Office 2013 suites and programs (MSI deployment) on a computer that's running another version of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2784668/how-to-use-office-2013-suites-and-programs-msi-deployment-on-a-compute)